# How to find conditional characteristic function if joint characteristic function is given?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, conditional-expectation, characteristic-functions

Let $(X,Y)$ be random vector and ${\varphi _{XY}}({t_1},{t_2}) = {\rm{E}}{e^{i({t_1}X + {t_2}Y)}}$ its joint characteristic function. How to find conditional characteristic function $${\varphi _{X\left| Y \right.}}(t) = {\rm{E}}\left( {\left. {{e^{itX}}} \right|Y} \right)
$$ Could you recommend the textbook related to the task, please?

Comment: Possible similar question in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482658/conditional-characteristic-function

Answer (score 0):

The task has been solved by M.S. Bartlett in his article "The Characteristic Function of a Conditional Statistic".